# Firefox renders wrong colors

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, mac, chromium

I've got the following problem:

I'm developing an website, so while I was testing around I've noticed that **firefox and chromium** display an css bar in different colors. When I switched between several machine I could come to the conclusion that **firefox for ubuntu** is the problem. On all other devices I've tested the website. It's perfectly fine.

Does someone knows why this is and came up with a solution?

Comment: Could you give us an example? Perhaps a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example that shows up the problem. I'm a webdev and I'm certain there are others here who can help but we need more to go on :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it wasn't something of the css itself. It was a software problem. But thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very strange, **probably is an old Firefox bug** already noted on [Bugzilla's Bug 629312](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=629312).
**The solution** might be to set the Firefox `gfx.color_management.mode` option in `about:config` to `0`.
This may solve the problem in your computer but not - obviously - in other machines: **to mitigate the problem on remote machines** use [Web Safest Colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#Safest_web_colors) or [Web Safe Colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#Color_table).
For the images, you can use GIMP to change the colour's hue; there is also a web safe image mode in `Image -> Mode -> Indexed...` that may solve the problem for some images (it's ugly but works).
 
Please note that using only those safe colors will enhance the accesibility of your website, it's always a good practice; you'll need an extra bit of patience, the world is full of software bugs.
Comment under here if you need more help and don't forget to press the up arrow if I'm of any help.
Have a nice evening.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! **gfx.color_management.mode** did the job.

Note: the up arrow requires 15 reputation which I haven't got yet.

Comment: I'm happy for you; +1 for the useful comment (you confirmed the resolution of a common problem). :-)

Comment: I don't have enough reps for it :( I need 15.. I've only 3.. a bit weird actually... imo.

Comment: To enhance your reputation here, make and answer useful questions; every action that helps the Ubuntu Community is usually rewarded with reputation and, often, with one medal. A good reputation will allow you to be a better member and will give you more abilities. Follow this link for more information & welcome to the Ubuntu community: http://askubuntu.com/help